# Weblogic and recursive JSP tags

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, weblogic, jsp-tags

I have a Weblogic 10.3.3 install and seem to be having issues with recursive JSP tags. On the internet I have found some other people experiencing the same issues ([here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/428667/BEA-Weblogic/JSP-Tag-Files-used-recursivily) and [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2457534)), but no solutions. Some people suggest that it is fixed in Weblogic 12, or was working in 9, but I can't confirm this.

The application is built using Spring/Spring Roo/Apache Tiles/jspx. The model class that is being displayed is something like:

```
public class Programme {

private String name;
private final List<Programme> programmes = new ArrayList<Programme>();

...(getter/setter)...
}
```

Then I have a tagx like this:

```
<jsp:root xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:coursedataimport="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/coursedataimport" version="2.0">
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <jsp:directive.attribute name="programme" type="package.Programme" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" />

    <c:out value="${programme.name}" />

    <ul>
        <c:forEach var="p" items="${programme.programmes}">
            <li><coursedataimport:programme programme="${p}" /></li>
        </c:forEach>
    </ul>

</jsp:root>
```

This doesn't work. When requesting the page, the application container seems to crash (probably some stack overflow, but I can't find it in the logs), and the application context is reloaded. In Tomcat 7 it works fine.

The exception shown is something like this, but I'm not sure if it's related (since it talks about the error page):

> [ServletContext@483389576[app:app-ear-0 module:appmodule path:/CONTEXTROOT spec-version:2.5]] Problem occurred while serving the error page.
>   org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tiles.ArrayStack at 
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894) at 
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:779) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) at 
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:821) at 
>   ...

Has anybody experienced these issues before, or is anybody aware of a fix? Any tips on how to debug this, or how to workaround the recursive tag (since I want to display a tree, it is a bit of a challenge). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to call the programme tag recursively? I have a similar issue. While calling recursively a tag file it works in Tomcat 6, but not in Weblogic 11.

Comment: Yes, that's the issue. Tomcat works fine with it, but Weblogic is a pita. We never found a solution for this apart from rewriting the code  so it doesn't use a recursive tag.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how to fix tag-rendering engine. But my answer is work-around how to eliminate recursion at all. Idea behind that any recursion can be reduced by usage of java.util.Stack. Then you can create field `indentation` that tells you how many spaces should be reserved to display tree-like structure

Java code on build linear list with indentation:

```
class FormattedProgramme{
   Programme programme;
   int indent;
}
...
java.util.List<FormattedProgramme> result = new ArrayList<FormattedProgramme>();
java.util.Stack<FormattedProgramme> programmeStack = 
     new java.util.Stack<FormattedProgramme>();
//you should know how to resolve root bean 'programme'
programmeStack.push(new FormattedProgramme(programme, 0/*indent=0*/));

while(!programmeStack.empty()){
    FormattedProgramme parent = programmeStack.pop();
    result.add(parent);
    for(Programme child:parent.programme.programmes ){
         //create child item with indentation + 1 
         //may be you need keep order of items - then reverse this loop
         programmeStack.push(new FormattedProgramme(child, parent.indent+1));
    }
 }
```

After that in JSP you can place something that creates padding (there padding-left of div multiplied by 10px):

```
<c:forEach var="fp" items="${formatted}">
    <div style='padding-left:${fp.indent * 10}px'>
        <c:out value="${fp.programme.name}" />
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```